# How to execute WHERE clause conditionally?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Hi I have a Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetStaffsAndClients]
(
    @staffIds nvarchar(1024)
)
AS
BEGIN

    declare @Address varchar (100)
    declare @Apartment varchar (100)
    declare @City varchar (100)
    declare @State varchar (10)
    declare @Zip varchar (10)
    declare @County varchar (100)
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

    /* Get Client's Residence */

    select dbo.GetClientFullName(s.FirstName, s.MiddleInit, s.LastName) StaffName, 
    dbo.GetStaffTitlesById(s.Id) StaffTitle,
    dbo.GetClientFullName(c.FirstName, c.MiddleInit, c.LastName) ClientName, 
    dbo.GetAddressByEntityNameAndId('Client', c.Id) ClientAddress

    from ClientStaff cs 
    left outer join Staff s on cs.StaffId = s.Id 
    left outer join Client c on cs.ClientId = c.Id

    where s.Id in ( SELECT convert(int,Value) FROM dbo.Split(@staffIds, ','))

END
```

I want the `where` clause to get executed only if `@staffIds <> ''` and not execute otherwise.

Please guide me how can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where 
    @staffIds = '' or 
    @staffIds is null or 
    s.Id in ( SELECT convert(int,Value) FROM dbo.Split(@staffIds, ','))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try composing the query first and store it in a string.

Then execute the string using EXEC.